# What does heightMeasureSpec = widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childWidthSize, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) mean?

Tags: android

In the following sample code, I find heightMeasureSpec = widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childWidthSize, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY).
There are two "=" in the code, is it right? is this Java syntax?

```
   @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        setMeasuredDimension(getDefaultSize(0, widthMeasureSpec), getDefaultSize(0, heightMeasureSpec));

        int childWidthSize = getMeasuredWidth();
        int childHeightSize = getMeasuredHeight();

        heightMeasureSpec = widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childWidthSize, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's allowed in Java.  It's setting both `heightMeasureSpec` and `widthMeasureSpec` to the value returned from `MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childWidthSize, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)`.